# SuppressWarnings not working on FindBugs

Tags: java, annotations, findbugs

I ran FindBugs on my Eclipse project and got a potential bug warning that I would like to suppress for a specific reason (outside the context of this question). Here's the code:

```
public class LogItem {
    private String name;

    private void setName(final String nm) {
        name = nm;
    }
}
```

When you run FindBugs on this class is gives you a warning on the `name = nm` assignment operation, stating: `Unread field: com.me.myorg.LogItem.name`.

So I tried adding this:

```
    private void setName(final String nm) {
        @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(value = "NP", justification = "Because I can")
        name = nm;
    }
```

When I do this I get a syntax (compile) error in Eclipse, stating:

> Duplicate local variable nm; name cannot be resolved to a type.

So then I tried adding the FindBugs' `SuppressWarnings` on the field itself, but after re-running FindBugs on the class, FindBugs is still complaining about the same line of code and for the same reason. I even tried adding the `SuppressWarnings` to the `setName` method, and still no difference.

How (*exactly*!) do I use this annotation to quiet FindBugs?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the annotation on the field and fix the bug identifier.  This works for me:

```
public class LogItem {
    @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("URF_UNREAD_FIELD")
    private String name;
```

Comment: How do you import it, what do i need to add for gradle dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

I have always used the built-in `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`, not that of FindBugs, and it worked so far. Also, for specific statements you may need to keep the statement on the same line right after the annotation. Like

```
    @SuppressWarnings("NP") name = nm;
```

Also, are you sure `"NP"` is a valid warning identifier here? I would try `"unused"` if nothing else seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @Peter but none of these suggestions are working. When I replace the FindBugs `SuppressWarnings` with the exact line of code your answer contains I still get a compiler error: `Multiple markers at this line - Duplicate local variable nm - name cannot be resolved to a type - Syntax error on token "=", delete this token - Unread field: com.me.myorg.LogItem.name`. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Duplicate local variable" suggests there's something in your code that isn't posted in your question...?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I got the same error from eclipse with just that class.  The parser seems to make a bad guess about what you mean when the annotation is in with statements.

Comment: `nm` is only defined once; that shouldn't have anything to do with annotations, no?

Comment: I think what's happening is that the eclipse compiler assumes that "name" is a type because that's what's expected after an annotation.  Then "=" is not allowed so it ignores it.  So it thinks you're declaring a local called "nm" with type "name".

Comment: `@java.lang.SuppressWarnings` cannot work with FindBugs, because it has `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` (i.e. it's discarded by the compiler). FindBugs analyzes bytecode, which is why it has its own suppress annotation with `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`.