# DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE SuppressWarnings FindBugs false positive

Tags: java, findbugs, spring-annotations, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to eliminate a false positive for DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
@SuppressWarnings("DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE")
```

`@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE")`

(based on [SuppressWarnings not working on FindBugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884606/suppresswarnings-not-working-on-findbugs))

`@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(value = "DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE", justification = "please go away")`

based on http://osdir.com/ml/java-findbugs-general/2010-06/msg00017.html

But none of the options is helping. Please advice.
Using Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More Googling + Experimenting and I finally figured out a way to do this.

Check `Section 6` under http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html .

You need to create your own XML file with all the custom supressions in there.
You'll then need let build.xml file know about this file via `findbugs.exclude.filter`

```
 <Match>
   <Class name="com.foobar.MyClass" />
   <Method name="someMethod" />
   <Bug pattern="DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE" />
 </Match>
```

No need to add the `@SuppressWarnings` tag in the method once this is there in the XML.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: If you are looking for a solution to fix Android build, add following to build.gradle:     findbugs {
        excludeFilter = file("findBugsFilter.xml")
    }

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem with this code:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @SuppressFBWarnings(value = "DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE")
    final SomeMockClass mock = new SomeMockClass();
    ...
    }
}
```

The `@SuppressFBWarnings` does not work here.

The solution here was to move the `@SuppressFBWarnings` up to the method level:

```
@Test
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = "DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE")
public void testSomething() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final SomeMockClass mock = new SomeMockClass();
    ...
    }
}
```

I like to keep the scope of these annotations as small as possible, so they don't suppress real problems. Here it seems to be necessary to annotate the whole method.

Comment: The actual problem seems to be that FindBugs doesn't allow suppressing `DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE` for **final** local variables (as in your example) when using Sun/Oracle's javac compiler, [as explained here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html).

Answer (score 3):

[As explained in FindBugs documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE), apparently Sun/Oracle's javac compiler often generates dead stores for `final` local variables. These DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE warnings cannot be easily suppressed.

Not sure why the XML filter does work (as in the accepted answer), though.